# How to get rid of delete icon in edit mode of swift tableview?

Tags: swift, tableview

[image]

When using the edit mode of swift tableview, icons for moving and deleting appear.

I want to get rid of the red part of the picture

Is it possible?

I just want to change the order in edite mode

I wonder how

Comment: Can you show the table view data source and delegate implementations?

Comment: Do you want only to remove the icon but still be able to swipe to delete?

Comment: I want to remove the icon and delete function

Answer (score 2):

In your table view delegate add the following

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
               editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
   return .none
}
```